# Replacing a character in a string based on position

Tags: string, perl, substr

I am trying to use Perl to replace a character in a string based on its position.

Here's what I have done:

```
my ($pos, $rep) = @ARGV;

print ("Give me the string: ");
chomp(my $string = <STDIN>);

print ("The modified string is ", substr($seq, $pos, 1, $rep),"\n");
```

When I run in terminal:

```
perl myprogram.pl 4 B
Give me the string: eeeeee
The modified string is e
```

What I want as output is: **eeeeBe**

Any clue what is wrong?

Comment: `substr` modified the string in-place

Comment: Thanks, @ikegami. Didn't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting [`perldoc -f substr`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/substr):

> An alternative to using `substr` as an lvalue is to specify the replacement string as the 4th argument. This allows you to replace parts of the EXPR and **return what was there before** in one operation, just as you can with [`splice`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/splice).

(Emphasis mine.)

In other words, `substr` always returns a substring of the original string. If you want to print the modified string, do it in two steps:

```
substr $seq, $pos, 1, $rep;
# or alternatively:
#  substr($seq, $pos, 1) = $rep;
print "The modified string is $seq\n";
```

Comment: That did the trick. I am starting with Perl. So was trying to understand how to handle the substr. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @feijao If you're not already doing so, I recommend starting every Perl file you write with `use strict; use warnings;`.